# Synchronization of client database with server database with filtered data

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server, microsoft-sync-framework

As per my requirement, we have several client machines, having SQL client database and they need to be synchronize with server data, but only data related to that machine. That means, a client machine represents a City specific data handling; so that client machine need to be synchronized with server database only for that city related data. I'm working with SQL server sync framework but unable to do as per my requirement. So kindly suggest me the right way to do this.

Comment: Sync Framework is a correct solution; you need to write your custom logic in the client..what is the exact problem you are facing with this ?

Comment: Can you please explain the client side implementation for synchronization of data; 1> Full sync from client to server 2> Partial sync from server to client (sync only data related to a particular City from server to client, where that client machine belongs)

Answer (score 1):

Sync Fx supports filtering out of the box. Have a look at the docs, even the basic tutorial/walkthrough in the docs supports something similar to your scenario filtering by city.